# Progress in table

Tags: html, css

Im trying to get a progress bar in a table with the height of the progress bar not altering the table height, my css:

```
  table#t
  {
    behavior: column-resizer;
    overflow: hidden;
    table-layout: auto;
  }

  table#t tr { height:1.4em; }

  table#t > tbody
  {
    padding-left:20px;
  }

  table#t > caption
  {
    foreground-repeat: no-repeat;
    foreground-position: 3px 50%;
    foreground-image-cursor:pointer;
    foreground-image:url(theme:tree-view-glyph-open);
    padding-left:1.4em;
    height:1.4em;
    line-height:1.4em;
    active-on!: is-on-icon()? self:collapsed = !self:collapsed;
    double-click!: !is-on-icon()? self:collapsed = !self:collapsed;
  }

  table#t > caption:collapsed
  {
    foreground-image:url(theme:tree-view-glyph-closed);
  }

  caption:collapsed + tbody
  {
    visibility:collapse;
  }
  p.custom > progress
  {
    behavior:progress; 
    background-image:url(images/progress-back.png);
    background-position:2px 2px 2px 2px;

    height: 8px;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 1px;

    foreground-position:1px 1px 1px 1px;
    foreground-image:url(images/progress-body.png);  
  }
```

my html:

```
<table #t>
<caption><font color="grey">Files</font></caption>
  <tbody .first>
        <tr>
            <td titleid="file1"><img src="../Icons/2002.ico" width=16 height=16 /><div style="width: 18px"></div></td>
            <td titleid="file1"><div style="width: 210px">Application.exe</div></td>
            <td titleid="file1"><div style="width: 60px">1.6 Mb</div></td>
            <td titleid="prog2"><p .custom><div style="width: 100px"><progress name="p2" maxvalue="100" value="0"/></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td titleid="file2"><img src="../Icons/2002.ico" width=16 height=16 /><div style="width: 18px"></div></td>
            <td titleid="file2"><div style="width: 210px">Archive.7z</div></td>
            <td titleid="file2"><div style="width: 60px">843 Mb</div></td>
            <td titleid="prog3"><p .custom><div style="width: 100px"><progress name="p2" maxvalue="100" value="50"/></div></td>
        </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is what it looks like without the progress bar:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pysq8.jpg

and with the progress bar:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCwmH.jpg

I've tried  tags and setting the height of the progress bar and table in css and html but I can't seem to simply add in the progress bar without losing the height.

Comment: Could someone add 'HTMLayout' as a tag please.

Comment: Did you try using `style="height:.."` in the progress bar code?

Comment: What you've posted is not CSS. What is it?

Comment: "`<table #t>`" ??? It should be `<table id="t">`. But also review your ID name, it should be something significant..

Comment: Have you tried using developer tools?

Comment: Dai, it's HTMLayouts implementation of HTML and CSS, basically its HTML and CSS in a windows control.